# React & golang app is not functional on safari but fucnitonal on chrome

Tags: reactjs, go, safari

I am using golang for backend and react js for fronend. the login, register, post and everyhting is functional into chrome, but these functionalities is not working into safari.

set up configeration of React app functionalities for safari

Comment: Could you provide some more details about what the problem is in Safari? Do you see some error or warning? If you check your server logs after trying to load the page in Safari, do you see any errors there?
Without any indication what the error could be, it's near impossible for the community to understand and give a helpful answer.